# postgres interval type arithmetic: confirmation of behaviour requested

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for someone to confirm that I'm understanding this correctly:
when I add intervals together in postgres it looks like the time elements get added and converted - so PT55M + PT10M => PT1H5M
However, PT23H + PT2H => PT25H

I'm guessing this is because you cannot reliably do the arithmetic in the date area without a specific date as a point of reference due to daylight savings and leap years.

The pg documentation says results can "cause unexpected results" - I just want to be sure that if i stick to intervals in hms I'm not ever going to get a number of days back in my answer if I just stick to interval arithmetic

Incidentally the PGInterval java type behaves differently.
There I get an answer of 65 mins. Would that be considered a bug or just a point that nobody uses this class for anything other than getting data in and out of the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, PostgreSQL stores intervals as seconds, days, and months. The separate elements are necessary because there aren't consistent conversions between the three types: for example, a calendar day could have 23, 24, or 25 hours due to the effects of daylight savings time. Months have between 28 and 31 days. Interval math is performed independently within each element. Adding seconds such that the result is greater than or equal to 24 hours will not affect the day component, neither will summing day components affect the month component.

Adding an interval to a timestamp is more complicated because all of the interval elements contribute to the result. The following SQL demonstrates some of the issues that can occur when adding intervals to a timestamp:

```
SET TIMEZONE = 'America/New_York';

WITH t(test_ts) AS (
  VALUES (TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2023-03-11 12:00:00'))
SELECT test_ts,
       test_ts + 'P1D'::interval AS add_1_day,
       test_ts + 'PT24H'::interval AS add_24_hours,
       test_ts + 'P2D'::interval AS add_2_day,
       test_ts + 'P1DT24H'::interval AS add_1_day_24_hours,
       test_ts + 'PT48H'::interval AS add_48_hours
  FROM t;
```

Running this query results in the following:

```
        test_ts         |       add_1_day        |      add_24_hours      |       add_2_day        |   add_1_day_24_hours   |      add_48_hours      
------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------
 2023-03-11 12:00:00-05 | 2023-03-12 12:00:00-04 | 2023-03-12 13:00:00-04 | 2023-03-13 12:00:00-04 | 2023-03-13 12:00:00-04 | 2023-03-13 13:00:00-04
(1 row)
```

From these results, it appears that the day element is added to the timestamp before the hour element is added as evidenced by `add_1_day_24_hours` having a value of `2023-03-13 12:00:00-04` instead of `2023-03-13 13:00:00-04`. This behavior should not be relied upon since it is not described in the documentation.

The apparent difference in behavior between PostgreSQL interval type and Java's PGInterval type is purely one of presentation choice: the internal representation is the same. It is not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is perfectly correct.

The difference that comes is because of how time intervals are treated in PostgreSQL. They are meant to be durations, and not intervals therefore the result can be inconsistent. It would be incorrect to consider it a bug just because of the inconsistent results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep in mind the distinction between the data value and the display of that data. Once a value is created (it is stored?) and subsequently used in an *internal* structure (which is irrelevant to you), but the display of value can be quite different. Any calculation/use done with that value will give the same results. The display is controlled by the setting of [intervalstyle](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-OUTPUT).

> The output format of the interval type can be set to one of the four
> styles sql_standard, postgres, postgres_verbose, or iso_8601, using
> the command SET intervalstyle.

Now to your question about *stick to intervals in hms* can you be sure to *not ever going to get a number of days*. No! OK a step back. If you can completely control the inserted values then you can be sure of that. But can you completely control it? Well how about a the DBA needs to run a quick fix for a production issue and being unwary of your hours only requirement enters a value of '2 days' instead of '48 hours'; or the use of your table gets expanded and the new requirement  calculates value as the difference of 2 timestamps. As I used to remind my teams *you are in the business of systemic control of miracles*. Other words how does you app handle situations that cannot exist? Is there a way to deal with it. Well, in this case, yes. Create a function that normalizes days to hours such as:

```
--- Normalize for Days Intervals to Hours
--- Does NOT accommodate a duration with years or months, but could be expanded to do so, at least for months. 
create or replace function interval_to_interval_hms( source_interval_in interval) 
  returns interval
          immutable 
          parallel safe
 language sql
as $$
    select make_interval( hours => extract('days'  from source_interval_in)::integer * 24 +  
                                   extract('hours' from source_interval_in)::integer
                        , mins  => extract('min'   from source_interval_in)::integer  
                        , secs  => extract('secs'  from source_interval_in)
                        );
$$;
```

Now add a column to your table defined as `generated always as`. Call the above function as the generation; then use that column in your app. You can now be assured of that you will *not ever going to get a number of days*. Some thing like:

```
alter table <table_name>
        add <hms_interval> interval 
            generated always as (interval_to_interval_hms(<interval_column>)) stored;
```

See [playground](https://dbfiddle.uk/wzGEbhe6) (demo) here.

Comment: A better approach to enforce interval columns to have only the seconds component is to add a check constraint to enforce the month and day components to be zero. The interval in seconds should be computed as `make_interval(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, extract(EPOCH FROM end_ts) - extract(EPOCH FROM begin_ts))`. This approach guarantees that the effects of daylight savings time are accounted for.